# Kuzco pots stack problem

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I get idea from the emperor's new groove video game.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtClbzUd4QI#t=160 At 2.40, he go to about 3-levels height.

The question is if Kuzco want to go to 10-levels height, what is minimal pots he needed ?

Let me explain the rule. I have to change some thing to make it easier. In the game, all these rule isn't 100% true. (about 95%)

- Let Kuzco's position and pots' position are integer.
- Let Kuzco can only walk, jump, use his head to put a pot on his back and carry it.
- Let pots are 1x1x1 cube shape.
- There is no space restriction. You can even use [Integer] x [Integer] as space if you want and 10-levels height position can be any where you want in your space.

**Walk**

- Kuzco can walk 8-direction.
- Kuzco can walk and fall from higher levels to lower levels, no matter different height.
- Kuzco can walk in diagonal direction if there is no pots that block the way, for example,

[image]

Number in each cell represent number of pots and height. K is where Kuzco is. Let Kuzco is at (0,0,0). Green cells is where he can walk from (0,0,0) directly. He can't walk to (1,1,0) and (-1,1,0) directly. He has to walk to (1,0,0) and (-1,0,0) before.

**Jump**

- Kuzco can jump 8-direction.
- Kuzco can jump to max 3 unit distance to same or lower levels.

[image]

Let Kuzco is at (0,0,0). Blue cells is where he can jump from (0,0,0) directly.

- Kuzco can jump to max 1.5 unit distance to +1 levels.
- Kuzco can't jump to +2 levels.
- Kuzco can jump in diagonal direction if there is no pots that block the way, for example,

[image]

Let Kuzco is at (0,0,0). Blue cells is where he can jump from (0,0,0) directly. He can't jump to (1,-1,0) and (-1,-1,0) from (0,0,0) directly because a pots at (0,-1,0) block the way. There are special cases that he can jump to (2,-1,0) and (-2,-1,0) from (0,0,0) directly in this example.

- Kuzco can't jump while he carry a pot.

**Pot**

- Kuzco can take a pot and put it on his back 8-direction.
- Kuzco can take a pot only uppermost pot and from only same level and +1 level.
- Kuzco can take a pot at max 1.5 unit distance in both from same level and +1 level.
- Kuzco can take a pot in diagonal direction if there is no pots that block the way, for example,

[image]

Let Kuzco is at (0,0,0). Orange cells is where he can take a pot from (0,0,0) directly. He can take pots at (-1,0,0) and (1,1,1) from (0,0,0) directly (A pot on floor is at z=0 and has 1 unit heigh). He can't take pots at (-1,1,0) and (-1,-1,1) from (0,0,0) directly because a pots at (-1,0,0) block the way.

- If Kuzco can take a pot, he can put that pot back to that place it from.

[image]

K* is Kuzco with a pot. Let Kuzco is at (0,0,0). Yellow cells is where he can put a pot back from (0,0,0) directly. He can put a pot back to (1,0,0) , (0,1,0) , (0,-1,0) , (-1,0,1) and (1,1,1) from (0,0,0) directly. He can't take pots at (-1,1,1) and (-1,-1,1) from (0,0,0) directly because a pots at (-1,0,0) block the way.

I know that if he want to go to 10-levels high, he needs 9-levels high pots stack. If he want to go to 9-levels high, he needs 8-levels high pots stack. So, the minimal pots he needed is at least 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45 pots.

But I don't know if he want to built 9-levels high pots, what is minimal pots he needed ?

This is how to play Kuzco go to 4-levels height with 6 pots.

[image]

First Kuzco can make 1-levels and 2-levels high pots stack from the floor(z=0). Then he has to jump to 1-levels high pots stack to move a pots in 2-levels high pots stack to another 2-levels high pots stack to create 3-levels high pots stack. Now he can make ladder pots stack to go to 4-levels height.

Comment: Is there a space restriction which prevents him from building a row of 9 pots, then adding one to the last 8 of them, then adding one to the last 7, etc?

Comment: @Peter Taylor I'm sorry. I forget that rule. There is no space restriction. You can even use [Integer] x [Integer] as space if you want (I just show only space I need) and 10-levels height position can be any where you want in your space.